# Jquery Clone function with eq(index)

Tags: jquery, indexing, clone

I have many similar divs with id's as tictab ..and i want make the first tictab unvisible and add a clone of it at the end. i am using the following code

```
$('#leftButton').click(function(){      
    $('#tictab').clone().insertBefore('#rightButton');

    $('#tickers').find('#tictab').eq(ind).css('display','none');

    ind++;  
});
```

Where ind starts from 0. But the problem i am facing here is that jquery is making the cloned tictabs also invisible for some reason...I'm guessing it is because of some issue in indexing of the eq() function. Can anyone please tell me the right way to do it.

Comment: What is the `ind` var here? It seems to be completely undefined in your code.

Comment: *"I have many similar divs with id's as tictab...*" Stop right there. Don't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have multiple element with the same id. If you need this type of relationship between them all, use a common class name, not a common id name. The id attribute is meant to be a unique value not found on any other element in the document.

It sounds as though you want to clone the latest `.tictab` element, hide it, insert it just before `#rightButton`, and show the previous hidden clone. If that's the case, the following will work:

```
$("#leftButton").on("click", function(){
    $(".tictab:last").show().clone().hide().insertBefore("#rightButton");
});​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/dpze5/

Comment: Ok i'll keep that in mind ..but that doesnt solve the problem..i just wish to know how does the eq() function index the newly cloned tictab div?

Comment: @SumitDutta Actually, it does solve your problem. jQuery will not operate the way you expect when you use the same id over and over.

Comment: But then the clones i am adding will also have the same id as the div from which it is being cloned ..won't that cause the same problem too?

Comment: @SumitDutta We're encouraging you to *not* use id attributes on this clonable element. Remove the id attribute, and use a class instead since you plan on having multiple copies of this element on the page.

Comment: Okay thanks for the advice ..I've got it working now using the classes :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `class` insted of `id` to identify different divs but with same class.